# Android custom permission system

Tags: android, permissions

I'm trying to add a new permission in the android permission system. What I've found out till now is that the android manifest is in this directory : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/packages/SystemUI/AndroidManifest.xml but the sms permissions are not included.

My question is if it feasible to create a new permission by merging the read and write permissions of sms or by modifying the code of the read permission of SMS. If it is feasible how it's done,where the code of the permissions resides and in which file those permissions are.

I have no experience with modifying roms,any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I have no experience with modifying roms` This has nothing to do with the rest of the question.

Comment: If you have a full tree checked out `grep -r` may be useful, if slow.  But why you would want that *particular* permission change seems a bit odd.

Comment: @Funkystein - untrue.  In practice, while answers are ideally generic, the poster's level of familiarity is useful both in interpreting the question and formulating the best response.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Isn't she asking how to send/receive an SMS from her app?

Comment: No.  Completely no!  The question is about modifying the source code of the android system itself - a less common development task, but still software development.

Comment: @ChrisStratton is right :) the question is about modifying the source code of the android system itself.